# How to use multiple ternary operator in asp.net using razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I commonly use the ternary operator for very simple conditionals, especially within HTML attributes. For example:

```
<fieldset id="Employee" style="@(Model.Type == "Employee" ? "" : "display: none")" >
```

But I'm looking to have a multiple ternary operator something like this but the below does not work:

```
<fieldset id="multi" 
   style="@(Model.Type == "W2" || 
            Model.Type == "1099" ? "" : "display: none")" >
```

Comment: What you have shown works just fine. What issues are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Html.Raw.

```
<fieldset d="multi" 
   style="@Html.Raw(Model.Type == "W2" || 
            Model.Type == "1099" ? "" : "display: none")" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather put such logic in my view model by introduction of new property, for instance `ShowMulti`, to keep my view very simple:

```
<fieldset id="multi" style='@(Model.ShowMulti ? "" : "display: none")' >
```

on view model side the property would look like this:

```
public bool ShowMulti { get { return Type == "W2" || Type == "1099" } }
```

As alternative you can also introduce a class in css called `hide`:

```
.hide {
   display: none;
}
```

and implement your logic just at the beginning of your view:

```
@{
   var showMulti = Model.Type == "W2" || Model.Type == "1099" ? "" : "hide";
}
```

and in your tag:

```
<fieldset id="multi" class="@showMulti" >
```

but this approach generally depends on the size of your view.

Comment: error: cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'bool' on here >> `style='@(Model.ShowMulti ? "" : "display: none")'`

Comment: I've proposed two approaches. In the first one - returning type of your expression is bool (whether to show the block or not), in the second one - resulting type is string with name of class. I think it is logical because name of class could change and you would be able to make this change without rebuild of your mvc project.

Comment: I've added example of property on view model for first case, to make more clear for you.